# Evaluating $\int \frac{2\ dx}{\sin x \cos x}.$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the following
$$\int \frac{2\ dx}{\sin x \cos x}.$$

Comment: Considering that typing your exact question into WolframAlpha gives a complete answer, (-1).

Comment: Way to go is by writing it in terms of $\sin 2x$ and proceeding by substitution, to let $t=\tan x. I have posted an answer in the previously asked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\frac{1}{\sin x\cos x}=\frac{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}{\sin x\cos x}
=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}+\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}
$$